# $_SERVER["CONTENT_LENGTH"] not set

Tags: apache, php

Is there any php.ini setting which could cause `isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_LENGTH"])` to never be set on one server, but work fine on another, where the application code is the same and php.ini upload settings are the same? In an uploader library I'm using, the content length check always fails because of this issue. On PHP5.3, CentOS and Apache. Thanks for any help

EDIT: I should add that in the Request Headers, Content-Length:33586 - but when trying to process `$_SERVER["CONTENT_LENGTH"]`, it isn't set.

Comment: May help , See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13 Note that the meaning of this field is significantly different from the corresponding definition in MIME, where it is an optional field used within the "message/external-body" content-type. In HTTP, it SHOULD be sent whenever the message's length can be determined prior to being transferred, unless this is prohibited by the rules in section 4.4.  (point 4.4 = http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4 )

Comment: request headers show up as `HTTP_*` prefixed.

Answer (score 2):

Content-Length is sent by the server application, it's not part of the HTTP request.

Your application is the one that will be setting that, however you should not be doing that from within PHP as PHP does this automatically.

---

If you're dealing with input from something like an upload, then you will only get the Content-Length *if* the HTTP request is not `CHUNKED`. When sending a chunked request, the data length is not known to the recipient until all the chunks have been sent.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is a 3rd party upload script, which is running ok on staging server and my local xampp setup. That's why I was thinking it must be some difference in server settings somewhere.

Comment: Its always best to make sure dev, staging and prod are all configured as similarly as possible.